# How configure android studio to see sub folders as packages?

Tags: android-studio

How configure android studio to see sub folders as packages in project view:

for example, i've this structure

```
java
    com
        example
            android
                app01
                    app
                        MainActivity.java
```

but i wanna see this way:

```
java
    com.example.android.app01.app
                        MainActivity.java
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to enabled "Compact Empty Middle Packages". Do this by expanding the left hand project view panel, clicking on the settings icon, and selecting "Compact Empty Middle Packages".

[image]